# Question about partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,0)=1+x^2$, $f(0,y)=1+y^2$, and $f(x,y)=0$ if $x\neq0$ and $y\neq0$ and I need to answer the following questions

1. Compute $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$.
2. Is $f$ continuons in $(0,0)$?
3. Do $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,0)$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,1)$ exist?
4. What is the domain of $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?

My progress

1)

$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1+x^2-(1+0^2)}{x}=0$$
and
$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}{y-0}=\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac{1+y^2-(1+0^2)}{y}=0.$$

2) Let's consider these curves: $\gamma_1(t)=(t,0)$ and $\gamma_2(t)=(t,t)$. For the first, we have

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}f(\gamma_1(t))=1+0^2=1$$
and for the second
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}f(\gamma_2(t))=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}0=0,$$ because $f$ is zero for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$.

3) The first must be
$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{f(x,0)-f(1,0)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{1+x^2-(1+1^2)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}(x+1)=2$$

and the second as follows

$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,1)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x,1)-f(0,1)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{0-(1+1^2)}{x}=-\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{2}{x}$$ that does not exist

4) In the item (1) we see that $(0,0)$ belongs to $D=$ domain of $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. For points like $(x_0,0)$, $x_0\neq0$ we have
$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(x_0,0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{1+x^2-(1+x_0^2)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{x^2-x_0^2}{x-x_0}=2x_0$$

So the whole $x$ axis is in $D$. Finnaly, given $(0,y_0)$, $y_0\neq0$, we have
$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,y_0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,y_0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{0-(1+y_0^2)}{x}=-\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{1+y_0^2}{x}$$
which does not exist for every $y_0\in\mathbb{R}$

Therefore, $D=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\,|\,y\neq0)\right\}$.

Comment: I believe that you have the same typo twice. I think we should have $f(0, y) = 1 + y^2.$ Otherwise, we cannot find $f_y(0, 0)$ because it involves $f(0, y).$

Comment: Thanks for warning me... I have just corrected.

Comment: For (2.), you appear convinced that $f$ is not continuous at $(0, 0),$ but you have a mistake in your work: $f(\gamma_1(t)) \to 1$ as $t \to 0$ shows that $f$ is not continuous at $(0, 0).$

Comment: For (3.), you have two typos: $1 + x^2 - (1 + 1^2) = x^2 - 1.$ Cancelling the factor of $x - 1$ gives $x + 1 \to 2$ as $x \to 1,$ as you have said. But also, the limit of $-2/x$ as $x$ tends to $1$ is just $2.$

Comment: Your first computation in 3) is not correct. For the second, observe that the function is not continuous at $(0,1)$ along the line $y=1$. I don't understand where your answer to 4) came from. In particular, is $\partial f/\partial x (a,b)$ defined whenever $a,b\ne 0$?

Comment: Typos in 2 and 3 correct, @Carlo

Comment: @Ted Shifrin could you please tell me the error in the first computation of 3? And give me more details in the second? For the 4) since $\partial f/\partial x(a, b) $ is really defined for $a, b\neq 0$, but I am not sure how about $x$ and $y$ axes.

Comment: You have now fixed what was wrong in the first part of 3. For my second remark, I was recalling that a differentiable function must be continuous. So if the function $g(x)=f(x,1)$ is not continuous at $x=0$, it cannot be differentiable at $x=0$. For your last question, think about the calculations you've done and think about the $x$-axis and $y$-axis separately.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin do you agree with my arguments for 1 and 2? For second part of 3, my computation shows the derivative does not exist. Since a derivative is purely a limit, is it not enough to conclude?

Comment: Yes, sure. It's fine. I was just giving you a conceptual connection to make.

Comment: Now I understand your point

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I finished now